Movie about ghost hunters in a haunted house who get rid of the wrong ghost
For the life of me I can't remember the name of this movie. 
I know it had three people, two guys and a younger kind of emo (I think) girl. She was there because she was the only one who could see ghosts. The ghost is trying to get them out of the house by scaring them but they get rid of it with an electromagnetic burst or some tech thing and then a second ghost gets loose because the first one was keeping her back. It ends with them starting to leave but the second ghost pulls them down through the ground, kills them, and then walks quickly toward the camera.
The time period of the setting was modern. They had lots of advanced equipment to hunt the ghost.
It's not an old movie. I don't know the year but given the special effects and HD it is probably no younger than 2010. It was not a mockumentary — the camera view was focused on the characters, not their POV. It was in English so probably an American made film.
It is NOT Grave Encounters as Google continues to tell me.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

No clue why this was put on hold after it was (vastly) improved. Voted to reopen & answer awaits.

The plot somewhat reminds me of The Haunting. Main characters were a man and two women (one of which was "sensitive" to the ghosts). The suspected ghost actually turns out to be a good ghost who was keeping the real evil at bay. However, they were not ghost hunters (they just rented the place for a psychological experiment), and your question very much focuses on the equipment they had.

Guys I found it. I can't believe it took me so long. It's actually a New Zealand film called The Dead Room and it was filmed in 2015 [for anyone curious]. This has literally driven me nuts I'm glad I found it. Thanks anyway ya'll!
